# Input Type Password Security Benefits During Account Creation

Tags: html, forms, input, passwords

What are the benefits (if any) of using `type="password"` vs. `type="text"` when creating a form for account creation on a website? Besides a create and confirm, is there a defined best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious reason is, that you can type the password, even if other people are watching the screen. Often i have this situation when i publish my desktop in a presentation, or if i need to give support to other users.

Besides hiding of the characters, the browser (or desktop application) will also prevent copying the content from the password box. This is one possibility less for other applications to misuse the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `password` type, the text will be hidden by black dots (or * or .) whilst `text` entries are displayed in plain text.

Also, if you're using forms with passwords, make sure to use `HTTP POST` as opposed to `HTTP GET`. Because on the latter, the entries are visible in plain text inside the options section of the URL (see the difference between `HTTP GET` and `HTTP POST` there: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

You can do that by specifying `method="post"` as an attribute of the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I might me wrong but as far as i know the only benefit of using type="password" is that another person can't see what you're typing. But the value behind that is transfered in plain text if you dont use https.